# Map API for Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, dictionary, swingx

I want to  visualise the geographic  map in the swing application. I found only swingx map api.

Do you know  other open-source map api?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [Geotools](http://www.geotools.org/), it has a good API and tools for geospatial data.

Comment: sure, if you have .shp files you can display them

Comment: Feras, do you know this map api provide us to generate our own .shp file with specific area forexample: Greece Map. and do you  have any example about adding  graphic item to this map view?

Answer (score 4):

You could use this mappanel in Swing:

http://mappanel.sourceforge.net/

This is completely open source.

together with openstreetmap.org maps.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thx for your reply, could you give me any information about whether this library can work offline?

Comment: I dont think that you can use this offline as it is. But OpenStreetmap uses a tileserver which is used by this library. So i'm sure you could (with not too much afford) implement some kind of offline TileServer class or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but here is a solution:

[Slippy maps for Java Swing GUIs: SwingX-WS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314468/slippy-maps-for-java-swing-guis-swingx-ws)

Answer (score 1):

hey have a look at SVG Batik of Apache at http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/ . I built an interactive game with svg file for country location on an african map.

Hope this helps.